# Display the contents of an XML file in an MVC view

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, view

I have a "Terms and Conditions" block in my MVC view. I want the contents to be loaded from XML file (in HTML format).

How do we make it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your HTML is written directly in an XML file with no extraneous markup (which I am assuming is the case as you didn't state otherwise), you can use this line of code:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(XDocument.Load(@"filepath").ToString()));
```

Which will spit it out directly onto the page. You need to include this using to make use of XDocument:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Comment: If you need to parse the file beforehand let me know.

Comment: thanks for this answer.. this is exactly what I was looking for... However, I am not sure what could be the format of XML file.. any guidelines for xml template?

Comment: Honestly you would be even better off having your terms and conditions set either as a `const` somewhere in your code, or as a partial view. I wouldn't go the XML parsing route because it is an extra operation that replaces something which is already integrtated in MVC.

Comment: oh.. that's right.. it makes sense.. sure, I am removing this xml thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

> XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations) is a language
>   for transforming XML documents into other XML documents,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) or other
>   objects such as HTML for web pages, plain text or into XSL Formatting
>   Objects which can then be converted to PDF, PostScript and PNG.[2]

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Cheers.